# Comparing between classes

Tags: c++, c++11

i got an class which creates numbers between 1-6 and another class which puts them into an array. How can i compare two arrays if they are the same? (so the commented line would work)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

class dice {
private:
    unsigned int number;
public:
    dice() {
        (*this).number = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        return;
    }
};

class dicemng {
private:
    unsigned int dice_count;
    dice* arr_dice;
public:
    dicemng(unsigned int k = 0) : dice_count(k) {
        arr_dice = new dice[dice_count];
        return;
    }
};

int main() {

    srand(time(nullptr));
    dicemng w1(5), w2(5);
    //std::cout << (w1 == w2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `w1` and `w2` are objects not arrays. If you want to compare them, then you need to overload the `==` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need an `operator ==` in the class, like this:

```
class dicemng {
    // ...
public:
    bool operator ==(const dicemng &other) const {
        if (dice_count != other.dice_count) return false;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < dice_count; ++i)
            if (!(arr_dice[i] == other.arr_dice[i])) return false;
        return true;
    }
};
```

And of course, provide the `operator ==` for the class dice as well:

```
class dice {
    // ...
public:
    bool operator ==(const dice &other) const {
        return number == other.number;
    }
};
```

It is recommended to also provide `operator !=` for both classes, so that you can compare for unequality too:

```
class dice {
    // ...
public:
    bool operator !=(const dice &other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
};

class dicemng {
    // ...
public:
    bool operator !=(const dicemng &other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
};
```

Btw. the class dicemng has a memory leak (it does not free the memory), so you should provide a destructor as well and delete the array allocated in the constructor. And to be fully correct, you'd need to provide or disable copy constructor and assignment operator. That's why usage of `std::vector` would be better, you would save yourself some headache ;)

Comment: My problem is that i get this error then: ..\wuerfel.cpp:27:21: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'dice' and 'dice')
     if (arr_dice[i] != other.arr_dice[i]) return false;   i have no idea how i can solve this.

Comment: "no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'dice' and 'dice')" means you have to overload `operator!=` for `dice`.

Comment: Yes, for the code I had there you'd need to provide operator !=. So you can either provide it, or use the operator == and negation (I've updated my answer to that case to be correct). Anyway, it is always recommended to provide both of them.

Comment: @E.Maskovsky it will give me the same error just with "no match for 'operator==' " . could u maybe give me an example how i can do the new operator? i tried it already but no verison works for me

Comment: Updated the answer for the operator == in dice and also the unequality operators.

Comment: @E.Maskovsky thank you! that looks pretty simple. guess i just thought in the complete wrong direction

Comment: Also note that you should provide a destructor to free the allocated memory, otherwise there is a memory leak (updated my answer with that note).

Answer (score 1):

By using `std::vector` and defining `dicemng::operator==` to use `std::vector::operator==`:

```
#include <vector>

class dicemng {
private:
    // `dice_count` becomes redundant since you can get it with `arr_dice.size()`
    std::vector<dice> arr_dice;
public:
    dicemng(unsigned int k = 0) : arr_dice(k) { }
    bool operator==(dicemng const& rhs) const { // `rhs` == "right hand side"
        return arr_dice == rhs.arr_dice; // Compares the contents of the vectors
    }
    // Common sense says if we define `operator==` we should also define `operator!=`:
    bool operator!=(dicemng const& rhs) const {
        return !(*this == rhs); // Implemented in terms of `operator==`
    }
};

int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));
    dicemng w1(5), w2(5);
    std::cout << (w1 == w2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sadly i didnt learned vectors yet. i'll learn that in the next 1-2 weeks i guess :/

Comment: `vector` is just a class. If you can use classes, you can use `vector`.